# Core Data - NSURL command and momd

Tags: core-data

I'm working on a project that uses Core Data and I can't seem to find an adequate explanation of why the following line of code in my program always returns NIL for modelURL.

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CoreDataBooks" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

This example is straight out of Apple's sample code and it actually works in their program, but I can't get it to work in mine.

Questions:
1) Does something have to be in place before I try to implement.  I notice the Apple solution has a "CoreDataBooks.DCBStore" file that I do not have.  I've tried a number of things to create this...No luck.
2) momd: I've read a lot about this and it seems it's quite a bit different than "mom."  I understand the "d" gives the dataset additional capabilities and in some answers posted here, the author indicated to use "mom" and not "momd" without a great explanation of why.  All the same, this doesn't work either.

As always, I appreciate your help!

Glenn

Comment: Check the spelling of your resource name. Make sure the model is included in the bundle of the target you are running.

Comment: Checked the first part (spelling).  No problems.  What do you mean by "Make sure the model is included in the bundle of the target you are running."

Comment: Select the model file in Xcode and check in the file inspector if the checkbox of the target in question is checked.

Comment: Took a while to find what you were commenting on, but I found it and it appears to be checked correctly.

Comment: Create a new model and try it with a different name. If it works, copy over your model from one to the other and delete the original one.

Comment: Will try this next.  Thanks for the suggestion and I'll let you know how it turns out.  Will likely take a few days to implement.

Answer (score 0):

So `-[NSBundle URLForResource:…]` is returning `nil`. That's supposed to mean the requested resource doesn't exist.

Fire up the Finder and have a look inside the bundle. Confirm that file really doesn't exist. Is there actually a `momd` file (or similar) there, but by a different name? Probably want to adjust your code to match.

If no such files exist, you probably need to add your Core Data model to your build target.

Comment: I tried creating an NSLog for the stuff on the right side of the "=" sign and found something interesting.  Still not sure how to fix it, but it is interesting.  It returned the following:  /Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/1DD67211-3503-4FF2-85FE-341BFA867F7B/CoreDataBooks.app/CoreDataBooks.momd...The problem is, CoreDataBooks.app is not a directory, it's the executable.  This is true for the apple provided app...very weird.  P.S.  I tried Finder and it did not find the file.

Comment: Nope, `CoreDataBooks.app` is almost certainly a directory; it's a bundle/package. Control-click it in the Finder and choose "Show Package Contents" to see inside